# Is necessary to learn options API in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-options-api

Is necessary to learn options API to understand how Vue works ? or can I just skip it and go directly to composition API in Vue 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to always have knowledge of **options API** as Vue2 totally depends on it, And also most Vue project ( Vue 2 or Vue 3 ) is written with **options API**.

Also, I think if you have a good knowledge of it, I know it has totally different syntax but they have some common concepts.